# shiny dynamic select input error

Tags: r, shiny

I learned to use dynamic select input in my shiny application from the Rstudio shiny examples (http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/update-input-demo.html). Everything seemed to be OK, but an error occurred. I tested a lot and found the error was due to the dynamic select input used (the observe function in the server.R). But I can't figure out how to fix it. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!
To save space, some of the code was not shown.

server.R

```
load("./data/genomicVar.RData")
load("./data/geneInfo.RData")

fetchInfoByMsu <- function(locus="") {...}
fetchSnpByMsu <- function(locus="") {...}
fetchIndelByMsu <- function(locus="") {...}
fetchSvByMsu <- function(locus="") {...}
fetchExpByMsu <- function(locus="") {...}
fetchInfoByBin <- function(binNumber="") {...}
fetchGeneByBin <- function(binNumber="") {...}

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$mytable1 = renderDataTable({...})
  output$mytable2 = renderDataTable({...})
  output$mytable3 = renderDataTable({...})
  output$mytable4 = renderDataTable({...})
  output$mytable5 = renderDataTable({...})
  output$mytable6 = renderDataTable({...})
  output$mytable7 = renderDataTable({...})

  observe({
    c_bin <- input$bin
    c_gene <- fetchGeneByBin(input$bin)
    c_gene <- c_gene$locus

    # Select input 
    s_options <- list()
    for (i in c_gene) {
      s_options[[i]] <- i
    }

    # Change values for input$inSelect
    updateSelectInput(session, "inSelect",
                      choices = s_options,
                      selected = c_gene[1]
    )
  })

  output$mytable8 = renderDataTable({...})
  output$mytable9 = renderDataTable({...})
  output$mytable10 = renderDataTable({...})
  output$mytable11 = renderDataTable({...})
  output$mytable12 = renderDataTable({...})
})
```

UI.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  fluidRow(
    absolutePanel(
      textInput("msu", label = h4("MSU genomic locus:"), 
                value = "LOC_Os07g15770"),
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel(strong('Information'), dataTableOutput("mytable1")),
        tabPanel(strong('SNP'), dataTableOutput("mytable2")),
        tabPanel(strong('Indels'), dataTableOutput("mytable3")),
        tabPanel(strong('SVs'), dataTableOutput("mytable4")),
        tabPanel(strong('Expression'), dataTableOutput("mytable5"))
      ),

      br(),
      p(HTML("<b><div style='background-color:#FADDF2;border:1px solid
             blue;'></div></b>")),

      textInput("bin", label = h4("Bin ID:"), value = "Bin1078"),
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel(strong('Information'), dataTableOutput("mytable6")),
        tabPanel(strong('Gene'), dataTableOutput("mytable7"))
      ),

      wellPanel(
        selectInput("inSelect", strong("Select gene:"),
                    c("gene 1" = "option1",
                      "gene 2" = "option2"))
      ),

      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel(strong('Information'), dataTableOutput("mytable8")),
        tabPanel(strong('SNP'), dataTableOutput("mytable9")),
        tabPanel(strong('Indels'), dataTableOutput("mytable10")),
        tabPanel(strong('SVs'), dataTableOutput("mytable11")),
        tabPanel(strong('Expression'), dataTableOutput("mytable12"))
      ),

      br(),
      p(HTML("<b><div style='background-color:#FADDF2;border:1px solid
             blue;'></div></b>")),


      right=5, left=10
    )
  )

))
```

Comment: Try making `s_options` a reactive expression.

Comment: What is the error message? Also, try using `uiOutput`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer using `uiOutput` for dynamic inputs, see this minimal example:

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    absolutePanel(
      #select bin
      textInput("bin", label = h4("Bin ID:"), value = 1),
      #dynamic options based on selected bin
      uiOutput("inSelect")
    )
  )
)
)
```

**server.R**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session){

  #genes dataframe
  df <- data.frame(bin=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
                   gene=c(12,13,14,21,23,24))

  #dynamic select
  output$inSelect <- renderUI({
    selectInput("inSelect", strong("Select gene:"),
                choices = df[ df$bin==input$bin,"gene"])
  })
})
```

Comment: I was wrong. The error wasn't caused by the observe function. Some of the functions (fetchInfoByMsu etc.) returned data frame of zero rows for some input data. Thanks anyway. The uiOutput is great and much simpler.